# Is there an XML schema for JCR (Java Content Repository)?

Tags: java, xml, schema, aem

We've been asked to provide content via API to the Adobe Experience Manager CMS (previously CQ?).

As we store our information in our own system in an XML database, it would make sense to provide some JCR-compliant XML which may have to be enriched by AEM. To make sure our XML is correct we would like to validate it before sending it to AEM.

But despite having spent quite some time looking for an XML schema (or a JSON schema), we cannot find one. Does it not exist, or does it have a different name? If there is no schema, how can one make sure the XML is valid?

Here is a code bit from Adobe's [AEM Github repository](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/main/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/text/v2/text/.content.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    cq:icon="textLeft"
    jcr:description="Rich Text Section"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"
    jcr:title="Text (v2)"
    componentGroup=".core-wcm"/>
```

There are namespaces which lead us to think that somewhere there may be a schema, but so far no luck.

Comment: By the way, if you have custom properties, beware of calling them something like: cn:myPropery, where cn is custom name, the idea is that anything like prefix:Property can cause problems when importing the content into AEM and you have to register these custom prefixes. See this: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-learn/cloud-service/developing/advanced/custom-namespaces.html?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

[OakPAL](http://adamcin.net/oakpal/) can validate the XML used to import nodes into AEM. It’s not a schema, as I don’t believe such a thing exists, since JCR node types (the thing described by the `jcr:primaryType` attribute, which is `cq:Component` in your example) can have declarations that aren’t static and, thus, not representable in schemata.

Also, I’ve only ever used it to validate entire packages (ZIP files) with nodes, not single XML files so maybe you’ll have to package up your XMLs in order to use it.

Comment: thanks Raphael, I'll have a look at this. in the end we will probably create our own (very basic) schema using our own `jar:primaryType`s etc.